# Is there any downside to not recruiting my friends?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

Near the beginning of the game, you leave Ram Village. Gray and Tobin join your party by default, but I only discovered that Kliff and Faye were recruitable by talking to them.

Are there any side effects to choosing whether or not to take party members with you? For instance, are there negative consequences if I take them in or leave them behind? This game is already quite different from other Fire Emblem games I've played, so I'm not sure what to expect.

Comment: The only downsides I can think of is that you don't have access to their support scenes, and if playing on classic mode (permadeath), you have a couple less members in your army to replenish any lost units. Not 100% sure there aren't any other downsides yet, though, so I'll leave this as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [list of playable characters](http://www.rpgsite.net/feature/5569-fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-of-valentia-guide-every-character-listed-plus-how-to-recruit-them), the only real effect of not recruiting units comes from if you choose not to recruit Kliff or Faye in the beginning. If you neglect to do this, you can recruit them as Celica.

Other than that, the only other effect of not picking up optional characters is that you'll have that many less units in your army and you'll be unable to view their supports.